# Is c++ the only language that works with mpi

Tags: c++, mpi, cluster-computing

I set up my cluster already, and I just want to know how to utilize it. I followed this [mpich cluster tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster) and got to the very last part where compiled the program..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int myrank, nprocs;
etc.
```

It worked!! Anyways I noticed that mpi.h is a header file being imported. Is that necessary for a program to use the cluster? So not just any old program will work? Where can I learn to write them if that is the case? Is c++ the only language that works with mpi? I'd like to write some more graphics capable programs and I've never done that with c++ so being forced into using c++ to use the cluster is not ideal, but I just want to know if that is what is going on. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Old programs need to be rewritten to use MPI in a way that will harness the power of the cluster. Sorry, buddy.

Comment: *"Is c++ the only language that works with mpi?"* No. Go and read the documentation. Also, one question per question please.

Answer (score 2):

[MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) is a standard. You will need to consult the documentation of a specific implementation to see what languages it supports.

[MPICH](https://www.mpich.org/) is one such implementation. From a quick glance at the [documentation](https://www.mpich.org/documentation/guides/) it appears to me that it supports C, C++, and Fortran.

If you want a GUI and don't want to do that in C++, there is nothing to stop you writing the GUI (or any other aspect of the program) in another language of your choice, and using C++ only for your MPI-related backend.

Comment: Any compliant MPI implementation should support C and Fortran but not all of them ship by default (in pre-packaged form) with Fortran enabled since Fortran compilers (and the associated runtimes) are not as widely available as the C/C++ ones. C++ was deleted from the MPI standard, but is still supported by many libraries (at least the pre-MPI-3.0 bindings).